# Laravel: How to view this S3 file in a browser

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I am able to force the browser to show the download box with the following code:

```
return Storage::disk('private')->download("cv/{$id}.pdf");
```

When I try to get it to display in the browser, using the following code, I get an error:

```
return response()->file(Storage::disk('private')->url("cv/{$id}.pdf"));
```

At first I thought that it was because the browser's permissions applied in the second case (not the server, which has an AWS key).  This does not make sense though, since the error is a 'file not found' exception, from Symphony.

The URL given in the error message looks to be correct.

Answer (score 3):

I have just had the same issue myself and here's my solution:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


$s3_filepath = 'path/to/file/on/s3.pdf';

$filename = 'example.pdf';

$temp_filepath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), '');

$file_data = Storage::disk('s3')->get($s3_filepath);

file_put_contents($temp_filepath, $file_data);

return response()
    ->download($temp_filepath, $filename, [], 'inline')
    ->deleteFileAfterSend();
```

I'm using this in Laravel 5.8, don't know about earlier versions.

**Here's an afterthought...**

After reading through the docs, https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#response-macros, if you need this functionality multiple times, you could create a response macro. This would also tidy up the controller. Untested, but here's the basics:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

class ResponseMacroServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register the application's response macros.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Response::macro('fileFromStorage', function ($disk, $filepath, $filename) {
            $temp_filepath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), '');

            $file_data = Storage::disk($disk)->get($filepath);

            file_put_contents($temp_filepath, $file_data);

            return response()
                ->download($temp_filepath, $filename, [], 'inline')
                ->deleteFileAfterSend();
        });
    }
}
```

...and then in your controller:

```php
public function viewFile()
{
    return response()->fileFromStorage('s3', 'path/to/file.pdf', 'file.pdf');
}
```