# Laravel S3 - arn and kms key

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

Client has provided me below details:-

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXX
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXX
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=XXX
AWS_BUCKET=XXX
ARN: arn:aws:s3:::XXX
KMS Key: XXX
```

Image is uploaded successfully on aws server. but when i tried to open the url, access denied is coming.

Image upload code as below :-

```
$filePath = "users/" . $user_id . "/". $name;
Storage::disk('s3')->put($filePath, file_get_contents($file));
$fileName = Storage::disk('s3')->url($filePath);
```

Comment: check AWS S3 permission access. Make object public to everyone to test: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/

Comment: client dont want to make it public, as everyone cant access it

Comment: yes, It's  just for a test. How you try open the file? You need use the same aws fwk, user and blah... You cannot open from a browser.. or you need expose a temporaryUrl with a expiration time after upload.

Comment: from browser i am trying to open the url.

Comment: check Theo's answer. It's a way to expose a "expiration" url. After 10min the url dies. If you need a 'private' long term access, you need to use Storage::disk('s3')->files('yourFile');

Comment: client want to keep file encrypted and want to open using key

Comment: Try to avoid mixed concepts. File encrypted and Public/private access are different things. If you need to read your uploaded file, use aws fwk. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55134844/laravel-how-to-view-this-s3-file-in-a-browser

Comment: I need how to do it using aws s3 sse-kms?

Comment: Great, sounds more like a "customer requirement". I never did it with laravel, but you can find a guide with the old way here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-encryption-client.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by default, AWS S3 implements this restriction for security purposes. You can meet your needs by doing this :

```
$publicTime = 10; // Your file will be available 10 minutes
$filePath = "users/" . $user_id . "/". $name;

// Upload file 
Storage::disk('s3')->put($filePath, file_get_contents($file));

// Generate temporary URL
$url = Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl($filePath, now()->addMinutes($publicTime))
```

With this method, you can keep your S3 buckets private while providing public access for your files.

Comment: But client is not ready to make it public

Comment: What do you mean by "client" ?

Comment: I am developer. Client means who has given to implement aws in his project